# HTML5 Canvas Proper Way to Create a 'Clear Canvas' Button

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm creating a draw app and have my clear button and function working.  However, when I click back on the canvas to redraw something, the old drawing pops back up.  I know that I need to do some sort of restore, but I am unsure how to go about it. Thank you for all your help.

HTML

```
<button onclick="clearall()"> clear </button>
```

Javascript

```
function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('board');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas2 = document.getElementById('board2');
    context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

}

function clearall()
{

    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to add `beginPath` for each new drawing. Without it, every one of your previous drawings will also be redrawn with the new drawing. (redrawing == back to the last beginPath, if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just draw a white square on the canvas to clear it.

```
context.beginPath();
context.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
context.fillStyle = "#FFF";
context.fill();
```

Comment: hmmmm this did not work, just clearing the canvas but it pops up again like before

Comment: When you say "it pops up again", what are you referring to?  If you're making a game that has a main loop, then your draw function will execute over and over again, drawing on top of the white square.   Can you post your actual code?

Comment: i mean the drawing that i erased will come back on the canvas after I clear it, once I click on the canvas again to create another drawing.  My file is huge so I can't post the entire thing but here is the Javascript snippet.                                                                  
function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('board');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');}
function clearall(){
context.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
context.fillStyle = "#FFF";
context.fill();}

Comment: Hi everyone thank you for your help it turns out that I had my mouse movements inside a shapes array so I had to clear that array as well in order to clear it permanently. I did this as so:                                             function clear_canvas_rectangle ()
        {
    console.log("init.js: clear_canvas_rectangle()");
    context.clearRect (0, 0, 620, 495);
    
    // Clear all current shapes from shape array so they are no longer being drawn.
    shapes = [];
    
    console.log('init.js: clear_canvas_rectangle(): shapes.length: ' + shapes.length);
        }

Comment: Glad you figured it out!